# Extract obfuscated email with hyphens in Java

Tags: java, regex, obfuscation

I would like to extract an email address which is obfuscated with hyphens in that form: `f-o-o-@-e-x-a-m-p-l-e-.-c-o-m`

What I did so far is:

```
String email = "f-o-o-@-e-x-a-m-p-l-e-.-c-o-m";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\w-)+)@-((\\w-)+)\\.-((\\w-){1,}\\w{1,6})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(email);

while (m.find()) {
    email = email.replace("-", "");
}

System.out.println(email);
```

But I wonder, what if the email already have a hyphen "-" for example: `foo-with-hyphen@example.com` or `foo@example-hyphen.com` if theos mails obfuscated the same way above, my code won't work. How could I solve this?

Comment: if the email has hyphens in it before the 'obfuscation' destroys the original source and there is no way you can extract it again.

Comment: Are all hyphens removed or are they padded by hyphens on either side?

Comment: Could someone explain where all the downvotes are coming from?  Four downvotes with no comments explaining why seems a little off to me.

Comment: @home - you might want to check the answers before you say that something is insoluble.

Comment: @home: the OP *did* specify the "encoding" algorithm.  It slaps a hyphen in between each of the preexisting characters.  It's not spelled out exactly, but it's pretty clear, if you actually read what was written.

Comment: I wonder why all those down votes for the question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is this:

```
String email = "f-o-o-@-e-x-a-m-p-l-e-.-c-o-m";
email = email.replaceAll("(.)-", "$1");
System.out.println(email);
```

The `.` pattern matches any character while `\w` matches only digits and letters.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you can just remove every other hyphen and that should be fine? By that I mean remove the hyphens at the odd indexes in the string.

I made an assumption that hyphens are padded with a hyphen on either side so the original hyphen is not lost, if that's not the case it won't work if they are not preserved in the same formatting, i.e. "e---x---a---m---p---l..." where the actual string is "e-x-a-m-p-l-..."

Answer (score 0):

try an example something like this

```
string email = "e-x-a-m-p-l-e-@-e-x-a-m-p-l-e---p-l-a-c-e-.-o-r-g";
string accum = "";
int index = 0;
int count = email.Count;
while (index < count)
{
    accum += email[index];
    index++;
    if (index < count)
    {
        if(email[index] != '-')
        {
            NOT_A_HYPHEN_ERROR;
        }
    }
    index++;
}
```

Like Jesus Ramos's solution, but warns you if the string you've put in isn't in the right format.

Comment: Point.  I suppose I have C# on the brain these days.  The conversion should be trivial however, and is left as an exercise to the reader.